# How would I go about displaying user profile pictures from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, display

The pictures are already in my database, and I'm trying to display them on a dropdown menu when they are signed in, in the top right corner of the window.
Here is what my website is currently doing:

[image]

The highlighted blue part in the top right corner is supposed to be where the picture is displayed, but it's apparently not showing up. But as you can see lower on the page my picture displays.
I'm not sure why it won't in the drop down menu.
The code for my dropdown menu is here:

```
<?php
                            include ('core.php');
                            include ('link.php');
                            include ('profile.php');
                            if(isset($_SESSION["steamid"]))
                            {

                            echo'<li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle profile waves-effect" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded=""><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="notifi-title">'.$steamprofile['personaname'].'</li>
                                    <li><a href="profile.php"><i class="ti-user m-r-5"></i> Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="usersettings.php"><i class="ti-settings m-r-5"></i> Settings</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="userhistory.php"><i class="ti-book m-r-5"></i> History</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="steamauth/logout.php"><i class="ti-power-off m-r-5"></i> Logout</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>';
```

Comment: What does *`$steamprofile['avatarfull']`* echo?

Comment: $steamprofile is the profile of the user, and avatarfull is the actual picture.
But the table name in my database is users, and the pictures are saved under the avatar row

Comment: So just remove avatarfull?

Comment: No, just use `echo $steamprofile['avatarfull'];`

Comment: Same problem :c didn't change anything

Comment: Here is my top menu:
<!-- Top Bar Start -->
              <?php include 'topmenu.php';?>
            <!-- Top Bar End -->
                          <script>
                $(".right-bar-toggle").click(function(){
                  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("right-bar-enabled");
                  console.log($(".right-bar").css("right") == "0px");
                  if($(".right-bar").css("right") != "0px")
                    $(".right-bar").css("right","0");
                  else
                    $(".right-bar").css("right","-266px");
                });
              </script>

Comment: let me make a clean link of my whole top menu thing actually. I don't see a query part to it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T5uSGc17

Comment: I have it set under a file called userinfo.php.
it says $steamprofile['personaname'] = $_SESSION['steam_personaname'];

Comment: It also has 
$steamprofile['avatarfull'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'];

Comment: @Jonny Dee, do you store image data or url in database? Can you post that part of the code too?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the name of the folder that has the profiles pictures on

```
<img src='folder/'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'' alt="user-img" class="img-circle">
```

Comment: They aren't saved locally it's all set up through mysql which is hosted externally on a virtual machine

Comment: i think you have to put some pictures to test .

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the url of the photo from the database table
2. Set a PHP Variable to that url ex.`$profileUrl = "URL";`
3. Find the DIV that is your profile image and set the background of the div inside of you HTML/PHP file

BELOW IS STEP 3

```html
<style>
  .profile {background-image:url("<?php echo $profileUrl; ?>");}
</style>

<div class=".profile"></div>
```

Comment: I know I'm dumb, but how would I go about selecting the url of the photo from the database table?
The table is users and the row is avatar, so wouldn't it be something like $users['avatar']?

Comment: Your not dumb... It took me sometime to figure this out too!

Comment: Basically just do `SELECT username, profilePic FROM yourTable WHERE username='$username'`    Then Basically take what you selected from the profilePic field of yourTable and it should work... I hope that makes some sense

Comment: I actually noticed that when a user signs in to my website, their "uniqueID" is entered, but my database is supposed to automatically take their picture and name from steam, which they sign in with. 
I'm trying to figure out why it's not getting those now. 
Do you think a script like this would work?
http://pastebin.com/i8P5J38b

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an `echo` in an `echo`:

```
echo'<li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle profile waves-effect" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded=""><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="notifi-title">'. echo $steamprofile['personaname'].'</li>
                                        <li><a href="profile.php"><i class="ti-user m-r-5"></i> Profile</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="usersettings.php"><i class="ti-settings m-r-5"></i> Settings</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="userhistory.php"><i class="ti-book m-r-5"></i> History</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="steamauth/logout.php"><i class="ti-power-off m-r-5"></i> Logout</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>';
```

Thus, you need to remove the `echo` in `echo $steamprofile['personaname']`.

Your code should be:

```
echo'<li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle profile waves-effect" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded=""><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" alt="user-img" class="img-circle"> </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="notifi-title">'. $steamprofile['personaname'].'</li>
                                        <li><a href="profile.php"><i class="ti-user m-r-5"></i> Profile</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="usersettings.php"><i class="ti-settings m-r-5"></i> Settings</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="userhistory.php"><i class="ti-book m-r-5"></i> History</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="steamauth/logout.php"><i class="ti-power-off m-r-5"></i> Logout</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>';
```

Comment: @JonnyDee This should fix the problem

Comment: This actually didn't work for me :c It's showing up exactly the same for me.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing out on an include('')?

Comment: @JonnyDee No, it doesn't matter. However, is `$steamprofile['avatarfull']` and `$_SESSION['steam_avatarfull']` blank? It seems like that it is not assigned

Comment: $steamprofile['avatarfull'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'];
is what it's currently assigned to

Comment: oh and yes that's all it's assigned to. :/

Comment: @JonnyDee Can you post the code where you assign the variables, the current code you posted have no problem

Comment: @JonnyDee Try adding `http://` in front of the link - `<img src="http://'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" alt="user-img" class="img-circle">`

Comment: whoa that actually did change it a little bit!
http://oi63.tinypic.com/elco43.jpg
But it didn't grab my avatar from the database :c

Comment: @JonnyDee Not too sure why, but you can refer to the demo on the GitHub page - https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication